# Bootstrap-vue b-dropdown ul menu set to hidden not display none

Tags: vue.js, dropdown, bootstrap-vue

If you check the bootstrap-vue documentation for b-dropdown you will see that all the dropdowns get `display: none` style while not active. And that is actually what I expect.
Just inspect any dropdown from the examples [HERE](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/dropdown).

But for some reason when I add it to my page all the dropdowns get `visibility: hidden`.
Since I have a bigger dropdown close to the end of the page this adds the scrollbar even though it is not needed. See the picture below.

[image]

If you hover the element on the dev tools you can see where the hidden element is.

[image]

Taking a deeper look in the dev tools I found this import

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/*!
 * Bootstrap v4.5.0 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2011-2020 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Copyright 2011-2020 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

...

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 12px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px rgba(17, 16, 15, 0.1), 0 2px 10px rgba(17, 16, 15, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 2px rgba(17, 16, 15, 0.1), 0 2px 10px rgba(17, 16, 15, 0.1);
}

...

.dropup.show .dropdown-menu {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

But I can't find this file inside my dependencies.

I'd be thankful if somebody has any pointer where to look and how to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Check your index.html, check if you are added bootstrap from CDN

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue - https://demos.creative-tim.com/bs3/paper-kit/components.html#dropdown-row

The project I'm working on is also using this kit which introduces some changes to bootstrap styles.